# Luigi: Task is never invoked

Tags: python, luigi

I have the following setup

```py
class TaskA(luigi.Task):

   def requires(self):
      yield TaskB()
      if not get_results_from_task_B_written_on_S3():
         print('Did not find any results and will exit')
         return
      else:
         print('Found results and will proceed')
         yield TaskC()
         results = get_results_from_task_C_written_on_S3():
         
         # do other stuff


class TaskB(luigi.Task):

   def run(self): 
      // process and write results to s3

   def output(self):
      return URITarget('b_path')
    

class TaskC(luigi.Task):
   def run(self): 
      // process and write results to s3

   def output(self):
      return URITarget('c_path')
```

The Luigi logs show the following:

```
Did not find any results and will exit
Found results and will proceed
```

To me seems like the control flow enters both `if` and `else`. Since this is in principle impossible I suspect that Luigi attempts to run the pipeline twice. Once it produces this

```
Did not find any results and will exit
```

Since it cannot find any results written on s3 from `TaskB`.
Then `TaskB` actually finishes its execution. Writes its results on s3. `TaskA` reruns. Finds the results from `TaskB` on s3 and produces

```
Found results and will proceed
```

But then it seems like the `yield` of `TaskC` is not working. It's just stuck there indifinitely.

This is just my assumption of Luigi's behavior. Please let me know if I'm wrong about this.

I need this modularisation of tasks B and C into separate tasks since it makes testing much easier. `TaskC` is a fairly complex tasks whose test setup would be much more involved than testing its constituents separately.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that requires() can get called multiple times during scheduling. Therefore, the first time your TaskA.requires() gets called, it yields TaskB. But the next time TaskA.requires() is called, you are yielding TaskB again and you hit the else block. That first call to TaskA.requires() is the only one that gets used for the actual scheduling dependencies.

I wrote a test program just to test this out and you can see in my output how many times TaskB.output() is called.

```
import luigi

taskC_complete = False
taskB_complete = False


def get_results_from_task_C_written_on_S3():
    return taskC_complete


def get_results_from_task_B_written_on_S3():
    return taskB_complete


def set_taskB_complete():
    taskB_complete = True


def set_taskC_complete():
    taskC_complete = True


class TaskA(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        yield TaskB()
        if not get_results_from_task_B_written_on_S3():
            print('Did not find any results and will exit')
            return
        else:
            print('Found results and will proceed')
            yield TaskC()
            results = get_results_from_task_C_written_on_S3()


class TaskB(luigi.Task):

    def run(self):
        print("Task B")

    def output(self):
        return print('b_path')


class TaskC(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        print("Task C")

    def output(self):
        return print('c_path')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi_run_results = luigi.build([TaskA()], workers=1,
                                    local_scheduler=True, detailed_summary=True, log_level='INFO')
```

This code outputs

```
Did not find any results and will exit
b_path
Task B
Did not find any results and will exit
b_path
Did not find any results and will exit
b_path
Did not find any results and will exit
b_path
```

Although the code is not a perfect replica of what you are attempting, here's the output from the scheduler which shows what will actually run:

```
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   TaskA__99914b932b   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   TaskB__99914b932b   has status   PENDING
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but read up on their [documentation](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies) on task dependencies. You're better off trying to yield other tasks in your run() function for TaskA.